# How to get page numbering format of any page

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, hyperlink

In some cases, the `page numbering format` of a some page has to be known, that is to say, the page number is a `arabic number 4` or `roman number iv`, as an example in the following code showes.

Then, in a large article with many pages and with different formats of page numbering(`Roman, ababic, Alph...`), how to get the page numbering format of any page?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\hyperlink{page.1}{page 1}
\hyperlink{page.2}{page 2}
\hyperlink{page.3}{page 3}
\hyperlink{page.iv}{page iv}% the page number "iv" has to be know in advance which is not possible in large article with many pages.
page 1
\newpage
page 2
\newpage
page 3
\newpage \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
roman iv
\lipsum[1-20]
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{page}}
\lipsum[1-20]
%Then how can I get the pagenumbering format of the Page 7?
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you generating the link text by hand rather than using `\pageref` which will automatically use the correct print format?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle pageref doesn't link to a page destination

Comment: no but you could use it to generate the link text surely? (but as you are here I'll let you answer)

Comment: @David Carlisle I just want to jump into any page. And only pageref to `section`, `table enviroment`, `figure enviroment` etc has link function.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, Frank asked me yesterday and I checked the code ;-). I can't answer now, only in the afternoon.

Comment: @lyl it shouldn't be to difficult to get a list of page numbers as hyperref creates it anyway for the page labels, but why do you confuse  your readers by switching from arabic 3 to roman 4?

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer for some reason, I'd like to change the format, For example, different part of the article(front matter, appendix, TOC...), different page layout(portrait, landscape) and so on. And also quick jump for going through the article.